# How to prevent events in Javascript+SVG

Tags: javascript, svg, dom-events

I've been confused with preventing unwanted events in SVG. To be short, on http://3lectronics.com/sof/prevDef.svg you may see example. Try to click on circle and draw line over the rectangles. While hovering, they becomes white.

Events are firing and I want them dead! 
Please show me what to do to shut down events on other elements while drawing the line.

SVG code

```
<svg id  ="svgRoot" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" onload="load(evt)" >

    <script type="text/ecmascript" xlink:href="prevDef.js"/>

    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#009399"/>

    <rect id="R" x="150" y="150" width="200" height="30" fill="khaki" onmouseover="this.setAttribute('fill', 'white')" onmouseout="this.setAttribute('fill', 'khaki')"/>
    <circle cx="250" cy="75" r="50" fill="blue" onclick="drawLine(evt)"/>
    </svg>
```

JS code

```
var newL;
var xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"; 
var cont=document.getElementById("svgRoot");

function load(evt) {
  var rect=document.getElementById("R");
  var offset=40;
  for (var i=1;i<7;i++) {
    var newR=rect.cloneNode(true);
    newR.setAttributeNS(null, "y", 150+i*offset);
    cont.appendChild(newR);
  }
}
function drawLine(evt) {
  if (window.svgDocument == null) svgDocument=evt.target.ownerDocument;
  newL=svgDocument.createElementNS(xmlns, "line");
  newL.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke", "black");
  newL.setAttributeNS(null, "x1", evt.clientX);
  newL.setAttributeNS(null, "y1", evt.clientY);
  newL.setAttributeNS(null, "x2", evt.clientX);
  newL.setAttributeNS(null, "y2", evt.clientY);
  newL.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke-width", "1");
  cont.appendChild(newL);
  cont.setAttributeNS(null, "onmousemove", "moveLinPt(evt)");
}
function moveLinPt(evt) {
  newL.setAttributeNS(null, "x2", evt.clientX);
  newL.setAttributeNS(null, "y2", evt.clientY);
  cont.setAttributeNS(null, "onclick", "moveLinEnd()");
}
function moveLinEnd() {
  cont.setAttributeNS(null, "onmousemove", null);
  cont.setAttributeNS(null, "onclick", null);
}
```

But, try link above.

Comment: Why not simply remove the event listeners that you're not interested in? Unrelated question: why do you set "onclick" and so on instead of using Element.addEventListener(...)?

Comment: Well, I thought that is the "proper" way to attach event listener with markup, and don't want to risk. Now, thankfully, you tell me not to be SVG-markup slave and I figure that.
If I get it right, you advice me to manage all events programmaticaly? Thanks to all here (both).

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want the rectangles to respond to mouseover then set pointer-events to none on those elements. For your example you could add this

```
var rects = document.getElementsByTagName("rect") 
for (var i = 0; i < rects.length; i++) {
    rects[i].setAttribute("pointer-events", "none");
}
```

to moveLinPt and if you want to turn events back on again you could add this

```
var rects = document.getElementsByTagName("rect") 
for (var i = 0; i < rects.length; i++) {
    rects[i].setAttribute("pointer-events", "visiblePainted");
}
```

to moveLinEnd

Comment: Yes, I know that. But in my application there's all kind of different elements, in different groups...in different svg tags.
There should be another solution. What about preventDefault, stopPropagation...or something like tis?

Comment: In that case you could create a visibility hidden rect and stick that over all the others to prevent them getting the mouse events.

Comment: Set a flag called "isDrawing" to true during the draw operation. In your mouseover events, check if !isDrawing. preventDefault and stopPropation won't work because they are different kinds of mouse events. In other words, keep track of what mode you are in at all times, and only do actions when you are in the right mode.